# IntelliJ IDEA Cmd+Shift+A (Find Action) causes error log: "Nothing appropriate" in a yellow terminal titled "apropos"

Tags: intellij-idea

When merging/rebasing branches I usually press cmd+shift+A and search "Resolve conflicts".

This works once per session and if I do it a second time the following error log pops up, and the cmd+shift+A window closes immediately.

[image]

A workaround is to close the project and reopen it (each time I need to resolve conflicts).

Anyone know what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an official [FAQ document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005137400-Cmd-Shift-A-hotkey-opens-Terminal-with-apropos-search-instead-of-the-Find-Action-dialog) for this problem:

[image: faq]